# summarize initial column mysql

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I have created a query like this

```
 "select count(if(gender="male",1,null)) as malecount,
  count(if(gender="female",1,null)) as femalecount from biodata"
```

it's work, and the i want to summarize that count like this:

```
 "select count(if(gender="male",1,null)) as malecount,
  count(if(gender="female",1,null)) as femalecount, male+female as sumgender 
  from biodata"
```

ofcourse that query will help when i make many conditions in if statement

please help me solve this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this way to solve issue

```
select malecount+femalecount as sumcount from  (select
count(if(gender="male",1,null)) as malecount,  
 count(if(gender="female",1,null)) as femalecount   from biodata) as
 query
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
select 
count(if(gender="male",1,null)) as malecount,
count(if(gender="female",1,null)) as femalecount, 
count(if(gender in ("female","male",1,0)) as sumgender 
from biodata
```

or if you are sure that all rows have either male or female as gender, use a simple count(1)

```
select 
count(if(gender="male",1,null)) as malecount,
count(if(gender="female",1,null)) as femalecount, 
count(1) as sumgender 
from biodata
```

or do a subquery

```
select
malecount, 
femalecount,
malecount + femalecount as sumgender
from (
select 
count(if(gender="male",1,null)) as malecount,
count(if(gender="female",1,null)) as femalecount
from biodata
) sub
```

but you cannot use aggregated aliases to calculate with in the same select.